# Testing in leiningen

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, leiningen

I am writing a small Clojure project using leiningen with the following directory structure:

```
project
+ src
  + org/example/project/core.clj
+ test
  + org/example/project/core.clj
```

When I run `lein test`, it reports that it ran 0 tests with 0 failures, but I purposely put a test designed to fail in the test/.../core.clj file.

I added the line `:test-path test` to my `project.clj` file and when I re-ran, got the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :as-file of protocol: #'clojure.java.io/Coercions found for class: clojure.lang.Symbol (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5440)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5391)
    at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2382)
    at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:235)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:254)
    at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:270)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:354)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:458)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:377)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:174)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :as-file of protocol: #'clojure.java.io/Coercions found for class: clojure.lang.Symbol
    at clojure.core$_cache_protocol_fn.invoke(core_deftype.clj:471)
    at clojure.java.io$fn__7328$G__7323__7333.invoke(io.clj:34)
    at clojure.java.io$file.invoke(io.clj:401)
    at leiningen.util.ns$namespaces_in_dir.invoke(ns.clj:38)
    at leiningen.test$test.doInvoke(test.clj:45)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:411)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:365)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
    at leiningen.core$apply_task.invoke(core.clj:156)
    at leiningen.core$_main.doInvoke(core.clj:212)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:138)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:540)
    at leiningen.core$_main.invoke(core.clj:217)
    at user$eval167.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
    ... 11 more
```

I am running Clojure 1.2 and the latest lein (1.3.1).

Looks like a problem with either clojure.core or the lein code.

Comment: are your namespaces matching your folders?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for the source layout. I think you basically shadow your test with the real core.clj file. That's probably why `clojure.test` doesn't find any tests. Did you try a different namespace and file name? eg. `test/example/project/test_core.clj`.

Comment: That worked. I thought the name should not matter. The file and namespace are now `test_core`.

Comment: @Ralph: well, src and test are not part of the namespace. Some both files basically look the same to the clojure process. So the first found will be used.

Comment: It's best if you create your project either using "lein new" or matching the structure you get from it.

Comment: @technomancy – it's also important to mirror changes (e.g. renaming a file/namespace) made under *src* to *test* (and vice versa). I had renamed *core.clj* to *web.clj* and didn't think to rename the corresponding test file until now.

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue.
After a while I noticed that leins default path to tests are:

```
test/{project-name}/test/{file-under-test}.clj
                    ^^^^
```

Note an extra `test` directory in the path.